# Rubyで配列を組み替える方法を知りたい

Tags: ruby

resultの２次元配列になるようなsplit内のコードがわかりません。
ライブラリは使用しません。

```
[
  {
    :type=>"h1", :value=>1,
    :children=>[{:type=>"p", :value=>2}]
  },
  {
    :type=>"h2", :value=>3,
    :children=> [
      {
        :type=>"p", :value=>4,
        :children=>[
          {:type=>"p", :value=>5},
          {:type=>"h3", :value=>6}
        ],
      },
      {:type=>"p", :value=>7},
      {
        :type=>"h3", :value=>8,
        :children=>[{:type=>"h3", :value=>9}]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    :type=>"h2", :value=>11,
    :children=>[{:type=>"p", :value=>10}]
  }
]

def split(obj)
  # Please this code
end

# result
[
  ["h1:1", "p:2"],
  ["h2:3", "p:4", "p:5" ],
  ["h3:6", "p:7"],
  ["h3:8"],
  ["h3:9"],
  ["h2:11", "p:10"],
]
```

Comment: 法則性がよく分かりませんでした。`result` の値はあっていますか？　特に元のリストでは異なる hash にいる `h3:6` と `p:7` が同じリストにいるのはどういう仕組みが想定されているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

あまりスマートではないですが…

再帰を使ってデータを取り出してから、flattenを使って1次元化し、hが含まれる要素から次のhが含まれる要素までを1つの配列(ary2)に入れて、ary2が次に移るタイミングでary2をary3にコピーします。
構造を壊してるので、(nekketsuuu♦さんも書いていますし、個人的にはハッシュじゃなくていいの？と思います)あなたが本当に欲しいものかはわかりませんが、参考まで。

```rb
def split(obj)
  b = extract(obj)
  union(b)
end

def extract(obj)
  ary = []
  obj.each { |elem|
    type = ""
    value = ""
    a = []
    elem.each { |k, v|
      if k == :children
        b = extract(v)
        a.push(b)
      else
        type = v if k == :type
        value = v if k == :value
      end
    }
    a.prepend("#{type}:#{value}")
    ary << a
  }
  ary.flatten
end

def union(ary)
  ary2 = []
  ary3 = []
  ary.each do |elem|
    if elem.include?("h")
      if !ary2.empty?
        ary3.push(ary2)
        ary2 = []
      end
      ary2.push(elem)
    elsif elem.include?("p")
      ary2.push(elem)
    end
  end
  ary3.push(ary2)
  ary3
end
```